# ERRO ao acessar chaves JSON com carácter especial

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Boa noite, Pessoal!

Estou escrevendo um NodeJS que acessa uma URL que contém um JSON nesse JSON as chaves contém carácter especial "-" que está causando erro na minha aplicação qual seria a maneira correta para acessa-las?

**Exemplo Erro:**

> var tocando = ('#TocandoAgora: ' +
>   parsedRadio.data.current-music.song);
>   ReferenceError: music is not
>   defined

**Exemplo JSON:**

```
data: {
    current-music: {
        singer: "NOME_BANDA",
        song: "NOME_MÚSICA"
    }
}
```

**Exemplo Código:**

```
const request = require('request');

request('http://myplayer.myradio.com.br/tocando.php', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error);
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
  var parsedRadio = JSON.parse(body);
  var tocando = ('#TocandoAgora: ' + parsedRadio.data.current-music.song);
  console.log(tocando);
});
```

Já tentei das seguintes maneiras e não obtive sucesso.

```
parsedRadio.data.[current-music].song
parsedRadio.data.['current-music'].song
parsedRadio.data.'current-music'.song
parsedRadio.data.currentmusic.song
parsedRadio.data.{current-music}.song
```

Me perdoem caso for um erro básico, ainda estou aprendendo NodeJs.
Agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que isso resolva, usei Object.values() para pegar os valores do objeto.
Se o objeto estiver dessa forma:

```
data: {
    current-music: {
        singer: "NOME_BANDA",
        song: "NOME_MÚSICA"
    }
}

const dados = Object.values(data); //retorno sera singer e song, dentro de uma lista
console.log(dados[0])//{ singer: 'NOME_BANDA', song: 'NOME_MÚSICA' }
```

Acredito que nao precise converter para objeto json, utilize ele da forma que vêm no body. Só usar object.values. Eu coloquei desta forma, mas se ouver um sub-objeto dentro do body ai sim voce deve colocar algo como `body.myobject` dentro do object.values.

```
const request = require('request');

request('http://myplayer.myradio.com.br/tocando.php', function (error, response, body) {
console.log('error:', error);
console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
var dados = JSON.parse(body)
var parsedRadio = Object.values(dados.data)
var tocando = ('#TocandoAgora: ' + parsedRadio[0].song);
console.log(tocando);
});
```

> [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: Boa noite, @AndersonMendes! Obrigado por responder! porém obtive o seguinte erro ao seguir sua solução `var parsedRadio = Object.values(body.data)
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: Extrai o objeto do body da mesma forma que você estava fazendo antes e depois usa object.value para pegar os valores do objeto.

Comment: Testei aqui do jeito q eu deixei e realmente deu esse erro, checa agora, modifiquei a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!